# How to plot a spectrum with plotly

Tags: plotly-python

I want to plot a spectrum that is given by an array of masses and intensities. For each pair I want to plot a thin line. When I zoom in, the width of the lines should not change. The bar plot does almost what I need.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go 

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(
    x=df['mz_array'],
    y=df['intensity'],
    width = 1
)])

fig.show()
```

However, when I zoom in the bars change their widths.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the dataframe and then used `px.line` to plot the spectrum:

```
def plot_spectrum(df, annot_threshold=1e4, threshold=0):

    df = df[df.intensity > threshold].reset_index()

    df1 = df.copy()
    df1['Text'] = df1.mz_array.astype(str)
    df1.loc[df1.intensity < annot_threshold, 'Text'] = None
    df1.Text.notnull().sum()

    df2 = df.copy()
    df2['intensity'] = 0
    
    df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values(['index', 'intensity'])
    
    fig = px.line(df3, x='mz_array', y='intensity', color='index', text='Text')
    fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
    fig.update_traces(line=dict(width=1, color='grey'))
    fig.update_traces(textposition='top center')
    return fig
```

[image]